# How to set video URL instead of local video resource for PIP feature?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-picture-in-picture

I am implementing Picture in Picture feature in android application. But I stucked to play the remote URL in Picture in picture mode in movie view for media player.

I am following the below google sample:

[android-PictureInPicture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PictureInPicture)

If anyone have idea. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.zoftino.com/android-picture-in-picture-mode-example) or [this](https://www.journaldev.com/20907/android-oreo-picture-in-picture)

Comment: @hoefling, No I have not tried this. I will check it and will let you know. Hows it helpful. Thanks a lot for response.